# search unknown character in a file unix

Tags: shell, unix, sed, grep

I have a file where I have to find lines having junk characters.

In the context, the junk characters is defined by the line having characters other than `[0-9]` `[A-Z]` `[a-z]` `,` `-` `.` `_`.

I tried below, but seems i am doing wrong.

```
grep -vE "[0-9]|[A-Z]|[a-z]|,|-|.|_" file
grep -vE "[0-9]*|[A-Z]*|[a-z]*|,*|-*|.*|_*" file
sed -e '/[0-9]*[A-Z]*[a-z]*[,._-]*/' file
```

Comment: And why do you claim that it "seems that you are doing wrong"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use character class alone with negation `^` at start - i.e print a line if it contains a character not among `0-9a-zA-Z,._-`

```
$ cat ip.txt 
foo_bar
foo;123
abcd
123
ijk*

$ # can also use: grep '[^[:alnum:]_,.-]' ip.txt
$ grep '[^0-9a-zA-Z,._-]' ip.txt 
foo;123
ijk*
```

Since `-` forms a range, use it at start/end of character class. Also, what characters are matched by range [depends on locale](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions)

Otherwise, you'd have to match entire line using `-x` option and `-v` option to print lines not matching this condition - i.e test if line is entirely made of only characters defined by `-0-9a-zA-Z,._` and don't print them

```
$ grep -xvE '[-0-9a-zA-Z,._]+' ip.txt 
foo;123
ijk*
```

Comment: Maybe explain in more detail how `grep -v` will print any lines which do not contain a match, which is quite distinct from printing any lines which contain a character which does not match. So `grep -v 'x' <<'xyz'` will print nothing because the input line *does* contain an `x` and not care that there are also characters which are not `x`.